# How to use VSTS to build a .NET solution that contains a .NET Standard project and a .NET 4.7 project?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-standard

I have a .NET solution which has 2x projects:

- .NET Standard 1.6
- .NET 4.7 xUnit project

Unfortunately, I'm using a package in the xUnit project that doesn't work in a .NET Core xUnit project, which is why I'm using a .NET 4.7 project for unit testing.

So, i'm not sure how to do this with Visual Studio Team Services.

Previously, I've just had a .NET Standard Project and a .NET Core xUnit project and have the following:

- Get Sources (GIT)
- Restore (.NET Core)
- Build (.NET Core)
- Pack (.NET Core)
- NuGet Push

So - how do I :

- restore + build a .NET Core project
- and then the .NET 4.7 project
- and then run the xunit tests for the .NET 4.7 project
- and finally pack/nuget push the .NET Standard 1.6 project.

please?

---

EDIT:

here's what it looks like on my LOCALHOST machine when i try and do a normal `dotnet restore`

Notice:
- `Hornet.Services.csproj` is restored.
- `Hornet.Services.Tests.csproj` is not located or restored.
- Both projects are in my sln, as shown above with the screen shot above.

```
c:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Services>dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for c:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Services\src\Hornet.Services\Hornet.Services.csproj...
  Generating MSBuild file c:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Services\src\Hornet.Services\obj\Hornet.Services.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Writing lock file to disk. Path: c:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Services\src\Hornet.Services\obj\project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 1.42 sec for c:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Services\src\Hornet.Services\Hornet.Services.csproj.

  NuGet Config files used:
      c:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Services\NuGet.Config
      C:\Users\Pure Krome\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
      C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      https://purekrome.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Hornet-Dev/nuget/v3/index.json

c:\Projects\Personal\Hornet\Hornet.Services>
```

Comment: does any of that not work? as long as a 4.7 SDK is installed on the build agent, the `dotnet` CLI tools should be able to build/test/pack the projects..

Comment: It didn't seem to FIND the services project because it's not built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many things going on here:

1. There are now many ways to create a .NET Framework xUnit test project - classic .NET projects or "SDK-based" projects. Currently, only .NET Core and .NET Standard project templates (as well as the "ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework" one) create SDK-based projects, but the `TargetFramework` property in the csproj file can easily be changed to `net47` from e.g. `netcoreapp1.1`.
2. By default, classic projects use a `packages.config` file for NuGet references. Only the `nuget.exe` command line can restore these types of projects. The msbuild-integrated way of referencing NuGet packages using the `PackageReference` items can be used directly via MSBuild using `msbuild /t:Restore` which is what `dotnet restore` does. This means that `dotnet restore` is unable to restore `packages.config` based projects. Note that even classic .NET Framework projects (non-SDK-based) can use the PackageReference style in VS 2017 versions >= 15.2.
3. The support for `dotnet test` is provided by the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`NuGet package and is meant to be used for SDK-based projects. This package contains the necessary configuration and msbuild targets to allow running tests via `msbuild /t:VSTest` - which is what `dotnet test` calls. Classic unit test projects do not contain or reference this logic and rely on a test runner to detect and run tests (e.g. the classic Unit Test VSTS task that uses a visual studio installation).
4. Even though `dotnet build` should be able to build many classic .NET Framework projects, many features may not work since the underlying build tasks are meant to be run on .NET Framework and may behave differently or are completely unsupported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild - e.g. `resx` files cannot use file references, assembly signing is limited 
   , COM references don't work etc. As a precaution or fix for these situations, use `msbuild` instead of the `dotnet` based tools. (`msbuild /t:Restore`, `msbuild /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release`, `msbuild /t:VSTest` etc.)

My suggestion: Create the test project as .NET Core xUnit project and change the `TargetFramework` in the csproj to `net47` so that you can use all of the `dotnet` tooling features.